# Postgres - Can not 'SELECT' from tables even though my role/user has been granted 'READ'

Tags: postgresql

I have an admin role/user and a developers role on postgres. The developers role enherits attributes from a 'readaccess' role which I created for convenience in the future. If I run \du I get:

```
    Role name    |                         Attributes                         |     Member of     
-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------
 developers      |                                                            | {readaccess}
 rds_replication | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rds_superuser   | Cannot login                                               | {rds_replication}
 rdsadmin        | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS+| {}
                 | Password valid until infinity                              | 
 rdsrepladmin    | No inheritance, Cannot login, Replication                  | {}
 readaccess      | Cannot login                                              +| {}
                 | Password valid until infinity                              | 
 admin           | Create role, Create DB                                    +| {rds_superuser}
                 | Password valid until infinity                              |
```

I have granted read access to my developers account and my readaccess account via the following

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO developers;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA mySchema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO developers;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO readaccess;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA mySchema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readaccess;
```

If I run the command \z on one of my tables in mySchema

```
myDb=> \z mySchema.myTable;
                                         Access privileges
 Schema  |          Name          | Type  |    Access privileges    | Column privileges | Policies 
---------+------------------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------+----------
 mySchema| myTable                | table | admin=arwdDxt/admin+    |                   | 
         |                        |       | developers=r/admin      |                   | 
(1 row)
```

However I can not run selects -- it says I have no permissions

```
myDB=> select * from mySchema.myTable;
ERROR:  permission denied for schema mySchema
LINE 1: select * from mySchema.myTable;
```

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to granting access to the tables, you must also grant access to the schema that contains them:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA myschema TO readaccess, developers;
```

Comment: How can I check which roles have access to a particular schema?

Comment: @J86 Using `\dn+ schemaname` in `psql`.