# Cloud SQL (postgres) cloudsqlsuperuser cannot view tables created by a cloudsqliamserviceaccount user

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I am testing the CloudSQL IAM [automatic authentication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/authentication#automatic)by using [IAM service account users](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/add-manage-iam-users). The goal is to deploy a backend service running in cloud with an service account (SA), which can connect onto a CloudSQL database without using password auth.

So this is what I did:

- Create a cloud SQL database `demo-db` via gcloud console
- Create a service account `sa` via gcloud console
- Create a backend service and run it in k8s with `sa` as the account, with the help of [cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-postgres.md#iam-authentication)
  . And make the backend service having liquibase schema migration so it can create tables
- Create a IAM service account user `user-sa` in `demo-db` via gcloud console
- Create a normal built-in user `user-db` (with a password) in `demo-db` via gcloud console (for my local login/psql to the db)
- Deploy the backend to production, and it connected (with `user-sa`) and created tables in `demo-db` (with liquibase)

And this is a problem I have now:

When I use cloud-sql-proxy to login the `demo-db` locally via psql, with user `user-db` and the password, I realise that I cannot view or select the table created by the backend service (via `user-sa`).

Then how can I view the data in the database as a developer?

PS: Fow now I don't have access to `user-sa` or `sa`'s secret/key files. As it is managed by our infra. I only have ownership of `demo-db` and I could give access right of my db to `user-sa` ...

Comment: Have you checked the permissions that have been granted to the newly created tables as reviewed on this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628567/postgres-can-not-select-from-tables-even-though-my-role-user-has-been-grante). This other [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168150/obvious-reason-postgres-users-cant-read-a-table) reviews common reasons why users cannot read a table.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52244674/13171940) also reviews a similar issue as yours.

Comment: Thanks, I think those answers could help. But perhaps I should be more clear in the question is that we are using [google k8s config-connector](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/sql/sqluser) to create instances and users declaratively. So I would like to figure out a solution that does not require too much of manual adjusting.

Comment: In order to fix the problems due to permissions over tables created by one account and unable to be accessed by the other, I've found [this problem](https://itectec.com/database/postgresql-how-to-setup-vault-and-postgres-in-google-cloud-to-have-the-correct-permissions/) that seems very similar to yours and would help you to fix the permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on AWS's Postgres RDS.

You (as the backend creation service) basically have to create a role, place your deployment role (`user-sa`) into that role and also your app user (`user-db`).

Then your deployment script will have to use `ALTER <OBJECT> OWNER TO <ROLE>`. Now every role or user in that role will have access. You'll have to do this for functions, tables, etc

Another alternative is to set default permissions via `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`, but note that those only take effect on *new* objects. If you add a new db role afterward and want to grant it permissions to a table that already existed, you'd still have to add explicit permissions for the new role.

`*` Note that in postgres, a role and user are interchangeable in commands. In my view, a role does not log in, but it can be used to hold a set of permissions. Instead of assigning permissions to individual users, assign them to a group/role, then grant the user membership to the group/role. Ensure that your inheriting permissions is allowed on the users and roles for this to work.

Comment: Thank you. But I guess the "alter ... owner" command you mentioned, have to be performed with the role/user of `user-sa` who owns the table in the first place? While that "ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES" perhaps can be run as `user-db` before `user-sa` create any tables?

Comment: I tried `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES TO "user-db";` as `user-db`, and deleted all the tables to let `user-sa` create them again, but `user-db` still cannot read those tables. Maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: If the owner is `user-sa`, that is the user that will have to grant privileges.

Comment: Thanks I see. Fow now I have this issue that I don't have access to `user-sa` or `sa`'s secret/key files. As it is managed by our infra. I only have ownership of `demo-db` and I could give access right of my db to `user-sa` ...

Comment: The permissions should be part of your deployed liquibase changesets. That way user-sa would be making the changes for you.

Comment: Indeed, that is something worth trying. Thank you.